# Visual Studio 2012 Lightswitch Application causes error 'GetAuthenticationInfo'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, iis-7, visual-studio-lightswitch

Cheers!
I've a problem with a deployed Visual Studio Light Switch Application. If i start the application out of my visual studio it runs without problems. After i deployed it to our IIS i get the following error:
[image]

```
Load operation failed for query 'GetAuthenticationInfo'. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.LightSwitch.Design.Server.Internal, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I don't really know whats missing. The application has been upgraded from a VS2010 to a VS2012 solution. After i fixed some upcoming build errors after the upgrade the program seems to run without problems in Debug out of Visual Studio.

Also i have running two other Light Switch applications which have been developed in VS2010. Both are running without any problems. Maybe someone knows how to fix this problem? Thanks so far!

**Edit 1**

Based on Matts reply i used fiddler to encounter the problem (*using the trace file gives no information about the problem. Poor tracing ;)* )

Fiddler encounters a HTML 404 Error:

```
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>
  <h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Further i found the following information in fiddler:

```
@Fault5http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none@Code@Value�Sender@Reason@Textxmllang�en-US��Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.LightSwitch.Design.Server.Internal, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.@Detail@DomainServiceFaultDomainServices  i)http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance@    ErrorCode��@ErrorMessage��Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.LightSwitch.Design.Server.Internal, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.@IsDomainException�@
StackTrace�   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainService.DefaultDomainServiceFactory.CreateDomainService(Type domainServiceType, DomainServiceContext context)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainOperationInvoker.GetDomainService(Object instance)
```

Seems like something is missing, but i dont know why

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this blog post on how to diagnose errors like this.  That should help lead you to the root cause of the problem.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2011/09/20/diagnosing-problems-in-a-deployed-lightswitch-application-eric-erhardt.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here

http://www.stefanjohansson.org/2014/06/error-load-operation-failed-for-query-getauthenticationinfo/

This appears to have quieted the error.

Answer (score 0):

I know LightSwitch is being retired, but for anyone still using it who encounters this error, my solution was to install all the IIS components - not just the defaults or minimal set.  Hope it helps!